Create Envelope in Docusign using C#
I need to create an Envelope using Rest API in Docusign, but I'm getting the response as
The URL provided does not resolve to a resource.
Tried the below code
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Value.BaseUrl);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("Sample.pdf");
    byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    // Add PDF document
    //byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);

    requestContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes), "file", "Sample.pdf");

    // Add recipient information
    var recipient = new
    {
        email = recipientEmail,
        name = recipientName,
        recipientId = "1",
        clientUserId = "123" // Unique identifier for the recipient in your system
    };
    var recipients = new { signers = new[] { recipient } };
    requestContent.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipients), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "recipients");
     
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("envelopes", requestContent);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Failed to create envelope: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }

    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);

    return responseData.envelopeId;
}


I would suggest you add the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/7.0.0-rc1
This makes things a lot easier for you. The C# code would then be found in this GitHub repo - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp
If you don't want to do that, you need to ensure the correct URL was used here.
The URL you should have starts with {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes
So it will be https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{Your GUID}/envelopes
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Value.BaseUrl);

baseURL will not be the URL you use to make API call, and I'm not sure what it is. It's most likely wrong.

The base Url I have added is https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/
When then creates a Request Url as https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/envelopes

That URL is wrong, it doesn't include account number, I'll update my answer to have correct URL

Then what should be the Base URL?
I had got this url from Chat GPT 3.5

You need to find out your accountID (GUID) and then you do what I wrote in the answer - https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{Your GUID}/envelopes

Go to https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys to find out what is your accountID
